# Use Taxamo as a payment pre-processor

Tags: taxes

The new 2015 VAT regulations of the EU are tough and Taxamo seems to offer a solution. The way it works is that Taxamo sits in the middle of the chain - between your site and the payment gateway. Taxamo integrates with payment gateways such as Paypal and Stripe.

The trouble is, then, to get CiviCRM talk to Taxamo. I don't know of any payment processor extension for CiviCRM that can do that. So I was wondering if anyone has an idea how to get a CiviCRM payment form work with Taxamo.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. The real need is to be VAT/MOSS compliant. I just don't know anything other than Taxamo that can automate that. If you know, please share.

Answer (score 2):

This would be implemented as a payment processor extension. There is not a current extension written for Taxamo, but the documentation for implementing one can be found [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Payment-Processor+Extension).

They also say (at the bottom of [this page](https://www.taxamo.com/doc/plugins/)) that you can contact them to see about getting plugins developed for additional shopping carts, the "cart" being a Civi payment page in our case here.

Comment: If you go this route, you may want to consider developing it as an Omnipay extension - this will work with CiviCRM and several other software packages as well!

Comment: @JonG Unfortunately, it seems like Omnipay doesn't support automatic recurring payments, which is an essential feature in our (and I presume many others') case.

Comment: @Borislav Talk to Eileen McNaughton - I think she's been working on recurring payments in Omnipay.